# Styling of Component.Apex.TabPanel (Dynamic visualforce tabpanel)

Tags: css, dynamic-vf-component

I have created a dynamic tab panel.

I wish to style this tab panel's tabs. These might happen using custom css but custom css is working for static apex:tabPanel and not for dynamic tabs created using dynamic component. Following is the code I am using in my VF page:

```
     <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myTabPanel}" />
```

And in my controller, I am calling "myTabPanel" as:

```
public transient Component.Apex.TabPanel myTabPanel {get; set;}
public DynamicTabsControllerOpportunity() //constructor
{
    myTabPanel = new Component.Apex.TabPanel();
}
```

In the above mytabPanel I am adding the child tabs. I wish to style the tabs shown in the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create dynamic component you can also set the attributes of that tag in the class. You can view all the available attributes for `apex:tabPanel` [here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm)

Now let's say you have css class, `tabPanel`, defined in your page then you can set the same in the apexclass:

```
myTabPanel = new Component.Apex.TabPanel();
myTabPanel.headerClass = 'tabPanel';
```